# What's the relationship between ContainerRequestContext and HttpServletRequest? How are they linked in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jax-rs

JAX-RS filters take ContainerRequestContext as parameters when filtering requests, but in the actual service controller, most examples I've seen get their context in the form of an HttpServletRequest like

```
private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

@Context
public void setHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    this.httpServletRequest = httpServletRequest;
}
```

What's interesting as well is I can set a property on a ContainerRequestContext in a filter like

```
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context){
    context.setProperty("MyProperty", "theValue");
}
```

and then retrieve it in the controller THROUGH the HttpServletRequest like

```
@POST
public Response post(Object param){
    if("theValue".equals(httpServletRequest.getProperty("MyProperty"))){
        // This works and evaluates true
    }
}
```

So, how are the ContainerRequestContext and HttpServletRequest related? Which comes first, and how does the other get created/updated from that?

Also does it all work the same for the Response context/servletRequest objects?

Comment: request you to respond yourself if you have an answer.